# Draggable and Resizeable of an image using jQuery with Angular9

Tags: html, jquery, angular

I tried to implement a set of jQuery code into Angular9. A 'book' image can be dragged into certain area (let say a chart) and make it resizeable within the area. See: http://jsfiddle.net/u0r6zbt3/.

However it returns below error:

```
error TS1144: '{' or ';' expected.
67   $(document).ready(function () {
```

Any idea to put jQuery format into Angular in a correct way? Thank you.

```
<div id="drag1" class="drag" style="background-position:center;"><img class="img" width="100" src="http://www.bradleysbookoutlet.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/bradleys-book-outlet-books-only-logo.png" > </div>

<div id="chartdiv" style="width: 100%; height: 500px">Chart</div>

<footer class="footer">
  <div class="container">
      <span>All Rights Reserved 2020</span>
  </div>
</footer>
```

js goes here:

```
import { Component, NgZone } from "@angular/core";
import * as am4core from "@amcharts/amcharts4/core";
import * as am4charts from "@amcharts/amcharts4/charts";
import am4themes_animated from "@amcharts/amcharts4/themes/animated";
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import 'jqueryui';

am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Employee List'; ...

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
      if (this.chart) {
        this.chart.dispose();
      }
    });
  }

  $(document).ready(function () {

    var x = null;

    //Make element draggable
    $(".drag").draggable({
        helper: 'clone',
        cursor: 'move',
        tolerance: 'fit',
            stack: '.drag',
            revert: "invalid"
    });

    $("#chartdiv").droppable({
        drop: function (e, ui) {

          if ($(ui.draggable)[0].id != "") {
              x = ui.helper.clone();
              ui.helper.remove();

              x.draggable({
                  //helper: 'original',
                  containment: '#chartdiv',
                  tolerance: 'fit',
                            stack: '.drag'
              });

              x.resizable({
                animate: true,
                 //aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
                helper: "ui-resizable-helper",
                handles: "n, e, s, w, nw, ne, sw,se"
              });

              x.appendTo('#chartdiv');

          }

        }
    });

});

        $(document).mousedown(function(e) {
        console.log($(e.target)[0]);
    // matches all children of droppable, change selector as needed
//    if( $(e.target).is("#droppable .drag") ) {
        if( $(e.target).is("#chartdiv .drag img") ) { // if this then the big book one works as the image is picking up the click
        //$(e.target).find(".ui-resizable-handle").show(); // click on the div
            $(e.target).parent().find(".ui-resizable-handle").show(); // as img is sibling to handles, you need to get the parent, then do the find.
                $("#tools").show();
        }
        else {
            $("#chartdiv").find(".ui-resizable-handle").hide();
                $("#tools").hide();
          }
    });

    $(function(){
        $('#flip').click(function(e){
            $('#chartdiv .img').addClass('drag1');
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: I tried to include what @Andrews Felipe suggested and it works. However, it now generates:    ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts: - error TS2769: No overload matches this call. The last overload gave the following error. Argument of type '{ helper: string; cursor: string; tolerance: string; stack: string; revert: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DraggableOptions'.Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'tolerance' does not exist in type 'DraggableOptions'. tolerance: 'fit', node_modules/@types/jqueryui/index.d.ts draggable(options: JQueryUI.DraggableOptions):

Answer (score -1):

You can write jQuery code inside the method ngOnInit, but before check if jquery it's global.

In jQuery module, jquery.min.js under ‘dis’ folder is not public. To make jQuery global, head over to .angular-cli.json file and pass reference to the jQuery file path.
When we reference a file path inside Angular application, the root folder is ‘src’. However, jQuery library is inside node_modules. We need to define the right path in .angular-cli.json file

```
../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js
```

To confirm this path, go to node_modules→jquery→dist→jquery.min.js. You will see the path, which means you have added jQuery library globally into this application. Don’t expect ‘localhost:4200’ page on your browser to reload itself since the file is outside ‘src’ folder. To make up for these new changes in the application, we have to rerun this application.

Done this, you can use jquery syntax inner onInit

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit(){
    $(‘button’).click(function(){
    alert(‘Wass up!’);
  });
 }
}
```

Font - https://blog.bitsrc.io/how-to-use-jquery-with-angular-when-you-absolutely-have-to-42c8b6a37ff9

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25996082)

Comment: Ok, I fixed it look again